# Populate Google Charts after Ajax Success with Dynamic Data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-visualization

I want to Load a Google Line Chart(Responsive) after the Ajax Success. I tried to put whole Google Chart code inside Success part of Ajax call but nothing works. Here is my code for Ajax:

```
$( window ).on( "load", function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
             headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{csrf_token()}}'
            },
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                'annual_capital_growth':annual_capital_growth,
                'property': property,
                'forcast_period': forcast_period,
            },
            context: this,
            success:function(data) {
                console.log(data.graphArray); /*This is where I inserted Google Charts Code*/

            },
            error: function(errorThrown){
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
```

Now my Google Chart Code is this :

Please note, my code is a responsive code which has some extra functions in the bottom for window resizing.

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {
  packages: ['corechart', 'line']
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawBackgroundColor);

function drawBackgroundColor() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Years');

  data.addColumn('number', 'Property Name'); 
  data.addColumn('number', 'Compute Times');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Compute Times2'); /*This is where I want to insert Ajax Data*/

  console.log("--");
  data.addRows([
    ['2018', 200000, 210000, 220000], 
    ['2019', 210000, 220000, 220000],
    ['2020', 220000, 250000, 220000], /*This is where I want to insert Ajax Data*/
  ]); 
  console.log(data);
  var options = {
    height: 350,
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom'
    },
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Years'
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Property Value'
    },
    backgroundColor: '#f1f8e9'
  };

  function resize() {
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
  window.onload = resize();
  window.onresize = resize;
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Does it show any errors? Be more specific

Comment: actually I received no errors in Console and page just becomes a blank white page.

Comment: What response did you get?

Comment: Nothing, I got nothing, but Now I have changed my code a bit with the help of my friend and now its working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first, you're using an old version of google charts.
`jsapi` should no longer be used, see [update library loader code](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#update-library-loader-code).

need to use the following library instead...

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

this will only change the `load` statement.

---

and speaking of the `load` statement,
it will wait for the page to load by default,
so you can use it in place of...

`$( window ).on( "load"...` and `$(document).ready`, etc...

recommend setup similar to following...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var options = {
    height: 350,
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom'
    },
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Years'
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Property Value'
    },
    backgroundColor: '#f1f8e9'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{csrf_token()}}'
    },
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      'annual_capital_growth':annual_capital_growth,
      'property': property,
      'forcast_period': forcast_period,
    },
    context: this
  }).done(function (response, status, jqXHR) {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Years');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Property Name');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Compute Times');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Compute Times2');
    data.addRows(response.graphArray);

    function resize() {
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    resize();
    $(window).resize(resize);
  }).fail(function (jqXHR, status, errorThrown) {
    console.log(errorThrown);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I did it with the help of my another friend, he did the same thing which you did, except
In your code we can see that the response I am getting from Ajax is being stored into a variable called `data` but just below it, we can see a declaration of another variable `data` so in this case the same name variable causes problem. We faced it too so we changed the Ajax response variable name to `response` because I have to use the ajax data somewhere else also. Thus, I am accepting your answer, also I was using old Code which you made me aware about.